# Avoid Django to strip text file upload

Tags: django

I've been asked to convert a Python application into a Django one but I'm totally new to Django.

I have the following problem, when I upload a file text that must be read to save its content into a database I find that Django is striping the "extra" whitespaces and I must keep those whitespaces.

This is my template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% if newdoc %}
        <ul>
        {% for line in newdoc %}
            <li>{{ line }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{% url 'exam:upload' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" content-type="text/plain">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
            <p>
                    {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                    {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is what I have in the views.py

```
def upload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = request.FILES['docfile']
            form = DocumentForm()
            return render(request, 'exam/upload.html', {'newdoc': newdoc, 'form': form})
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    return render(request, 'exam/upload.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

And this is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file',
        help_text='max. 42 megabytes'
)
```

Now when I upload the file, it shows a random line like this:

```
"09000021009296401 02 b a b a b b b d b b d d a +8589 +03+6942 +03+1461 +00+5093 +00+2 +00+9237 +01+60 +01+00 +00"
```

While it should be this:

```
"09000021009296401 02 b   a          b   a     b    b    b d  b    b      d    d                a                        +8589  +03+6942  +03+1461  +00+5093  +00+2     +00+9237  +01+60    +01+00    +00                    "
```

I must keep the extra spaces and they save this information into a database, which I cannot correctly do if I don't have all the spaces that the file has.

Also, before you ask, It is not related with the print format of Django, since in a previous test I already tryed to save the information into the model, but it has the same problem with spaces.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the template as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% if newdoc %}
    <pre><code>{% for line in newdoc %}{{ line|safe }}{% endfor %}</code></pre>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{% url 'exam:upload' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" content-type="text/plain">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
            <p>
                    {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                    {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
```